# Double series convergence

Tags: real-analysis

Does this double series converge? Thanks in advance!
$$
\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty\frac{k}{n(n+k)^2\log^2k}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n(n+k)^2}$ behaves like $\frac{\log k}{k^2}$ and $\sum_{k\geq 2}\frac{1}{k\log k}$ **is not** converging due to Cauchy's condensation test, hence the answer is negative. You may check the first part of my answer through summation by parts, the [EML formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) or creative telescoping.

Comment: @user299621: you're welcome.

Comment: What is the EMC formula?

Comment: @Cm7F7Bb: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula

Answer (score 0):

We can also estimate the sum over $n$ this way:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+k)^2} \ge \int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{x(x+k)^2}= \frac{1}{k^2}\int_{1/k}^\infty \frac{1}{y(y+1)^2}\,dy$$ $$ > \frac{1}{k^2}\int_{1/k}^1 \frac{dy}{y(y+1)^2} > \frac{1}{4k^2}\int_{1/k}^1 \frac{dy}{y} = \frac{\ln k}{4k^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

taking $$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \sum _{j=0}^{\infty } \frac{(k+2) z^{j+k}}{(j+1) (j+k+2+1)^2 \log ^2(k+2)}$$ has a pole in z=1 and the values
[image]

Comment: @Charlessiva, why did you modify the original series for the generating function?

Comment: it is the same sum